# How can I get beyond the initial SeaBIOS page

Tags: usb

Recently I have been trying to boot from the usb port.  I had thought to myself that success was near. I had installed John Lewis' Boot_Stub, and yet, I could not get a bootable usb device to launch. And now, I turn on the laptop (Acer CB3-531) and I cannot proceed beyond the initial SeaBIOS page...I've tried to get beyond the SeaBIOS page in order to run a recovery file, on the two times I did get beyond the initial SeaBIOS page I ran the recovery file, got as far as being asked to provide my e-mail then password. Both times I entered the e-mail, but when I entered the password the computer buffered for several minutes before returning a "can't validate the password."

Please help! This is my only computer...is there a way to fix this issue or do I need to buy another device. I have in fact read the suggested solutions you provided, yet, I am nonetheless stuck in the creek of SeaBIOS without a paddle.